# Java 2D array to hold distance

Tags: java, arrays

I am implementing the travelling salesman problem and I need for example 5 cities where there is a distance,d, between each city, i.e

0 -d- 0 -d- 0 -d- 0 -d- 0    (where 0 is a city and d is the distance)

I am defining the cities as follow:

```
int[][] cities = new int[1][5];
```

how can I specify what is the distance between 2 cities in Java?

I am doing as below but I am getting "] expected "

```
int[][] cities = new int[1][5];
    cities[0][0] = 10;
    cities[0][1] = 10;
    cities[0][2] = 10;
    cities[0][3] = 10;
    cities[0][4] = 10;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I am doing as below but I am getting "] expected "

Comment: An error message? What line is it on?

Comment: yes an error message at cities[0][0] = 10;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cities[0][1] = distanceBetweenFirstTwoCities;
```

Comment: Why is it even a 2d array?